# How can I index files only from specific folder of my public/ - Nginx?

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

I have 2 txt files that I placed at /home/forge/laravel58/public/files;
I want to index those 2 txt files when I goto my `site/files`

I've tried

```
location /files {
    #auth_basic "Restricted";
    #auth_basic_user_file /home/forge/laravel58/.htpasswd;
    alias /home/forge/laravel58/public/files;
    autoindex on;
}
```

Go to : `site/files`, and see

> 403 Forbidden Nginx

Comment: Is there any information in the error log?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with how Nginx does user permissions, but you might want to make sure it has access to the files - compare their permissions and SELinux configuration to those in your base site with `ls -AlZ`.

Answer (score 8):

The trailing slash is essential for `autoindex` to work, it should be:

```
location /files/ {
  alias /home/forge/laravel58/public/files/;
  autoindex on;
}
```

Next, check that nginx has execute permissions (`+x`) on *every folder in the path*.

After that remove any *index file* from this folder, by default it's `index.html`.

And finally, check that your `location /` directive has attempt to try directories:

```
location / {
  ...
  try_files $uri $uri/ ...;
                 ^^^^^
}
```

Answer (score 2):

why nginx if you want you can use symbolic link

usage : `ln -s /path/to/file /path/to/symlink`

`ln -s /home/forge/laravel58/public/files site/files` with full path

Comment: If I go to my `http://site.test/files`. Will I see those 2 text files ? If I try your suggestion ... Are you sure you understand what I am trying to do ?

Comment: did you try this one ?

location /files/ {
            alias /home/forge/laravel58/public/files;
        }

also you can find this path correct file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled

Comment: can you check these https://www.ionos.com/community/server-cloud-infrastructure/nginx/solve-an-nginx-403-forbidden-error/

Answer (score 2):

1. The other answer about trailing slash being "essential for `autoindex` to work" is 100% incorrect: trailing slash is not required here, although, it is, in actuality, the preferred paradigm, because otherwise you make it possible to access both regular files and directories like `/filesSECRET`, one level up from `/files/`, opening yourself to potential security issues.
2. In your situation, where `/files` is the suffix of both the `location`, as well as `alias`, it is preferred to use `root` instead of `alias`.  See http://nginx.org/r/alias and http://nginx.org/r/root.
3. In order for http://nginx.org/r/autoindex to work, the UNIX user under which the nginx process is running must have "read" permission on the final directory of the path, as well as "execute" permissions for every part of the path.

   You can use [`stat(1)`](http://mdoc.su/-/stat.1), or `ls -l`, to examine permissions, and [chmod(1)](http://mdoc.su/-/chmod.1) to change the permissions.  You'd probably want `o+rx` on `/home/forge/laravel58/public/files`, as well as `o+x` on every single directory that's leading to the above one.

Comment: [ngx_http_autoindex_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_autoindex_module.html): _The `ngx_http_autoindex_module` module processes **requests ending with the slash character (‘/’)** and produces a directory listing._

Comment: @Styx yes — ***requests***, not anything else.

Answer (score 1):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.old-name.com;
    return 301 $scheme://www.new-name.com$request_uri;
}
```

[SOURCE](https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/)